# Ansible not able to provision Vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

The `Vagrantfile` in question:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "kurseve"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.playbook = "tasks/main.yml"
  end
end
```

I am trying to call `tasks/main.yml` ansible-playbook which looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: kurseve
  tasks:
      - name: update apt cache
        apt: update_cache=True

      - name: Installing developer tools
        apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
        with_items:
            - build-essential 
            - cmake 
            - git 
            - pkg-config  # used to configure our build
            - wget

      - name: Installing Image I/O packages required by Open-CV
        apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
        with_items:
            - libjpeg8-dev
            - libtiff5-dev
```

But when I do a `$ vagrant up` I get the following traceback

```
$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20170213.0.0'. The latest is version '20170222.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: kurseve-playbook_default_1488118172711_3988
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/user/development/projects/kurseve-playbook
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --limit="default" --inventory-file=/Users/user/development/projects/kurseve-playbook/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory -v tasks/main.yml
No config file found; using defaults

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

The directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── Vagrantfile
└── tasks
    └── main.yml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining the machine (`config.vm.define`) in your `Vagrantfile`, so the virtual machine will be known to Vagrant (and Ansible) as `default`.

You need either to amend the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: default
  tasks:
    ...
```

Or add `config.vm.define` to the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "kurseve"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.define "kurseve"

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.playbook = "tasks/main.yml"
  end
end
```

Or use a multi-machine syntax:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|    
  config.vm.define "kurseve" do |server|
    server.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    server.vm.hostname = "kurseve"
    server.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = "1024"
    end
    server.ssh.insert_key = false
    server.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.verbose = "v"
      ansible.playbook = "tasks/main.yml"
    end
  end
end
```